# Direct boot broadcast receiver to schedule alarms does not work if the screen is locked by PIN/pattern/password

Tags: android

I'm working on building an alarm clock app. The end goal is to add a specific feature to it, but right now I'm working on making it function as a regular alarm clock.

One obvious requirement of an alarm clock app is that if you set an alarm and then the device reboots before the alarm goes off, the alarm should still ring at the specific time, even if the user has not unlocked the device yet. I have tested on Android 11 and 13 and have observed the following: It works as expected if the device does not have a PIN/pattern/password lock (i.e. only swipe or no lock). However, if it does have a PIN/pattern/password lock, then the alarm does not ring even after the user unlocks the device. I thought that setting `android:directBootAware="true"`, using the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, and listening for `ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` was meant specifically for that, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here is the code for the Android manifest, with some sensitive information removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="[REDACTED]">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AlarmApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="[REDACTED]">
        <activity
            android:name=".features.alarmring.RingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.mainscreen.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".features.alarmscheduling.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:name=".features.alarmscheduling.RescheduleOnBootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".features.alarmring.AlarmService" />
        <service android:name=".features.alarmscheduling.RescheduleOnBootService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the code for the `RescheduleOnBootBroadcastReceiver` that is supposed to be called when the phone is restarted:

```
class RescheduleOnBootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reschedule on reboot received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            startRescheduleOnBootService(context)
        }
    }

    private fun startRescheduleOnBootService(context: Context?) {
        val intentService = Intent(context, RescheduleOnBootService::class.java)
        context?.startForegroundService(intentService)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `RescheduleOnBootService` that the broadcast receiver launches:

```
class RescheduleOnBootService : LifecycleService() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        val db = AlarmDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)
        val repository = AlarmRepository(db.alarmDao())

        repository.allAlarms.asLiveData().observe(this) { alarms ->
            for (alarm in alarms) {
                if (alarm.isOn) scheduleAlarm(applicationContext, alarm)
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        super.onBind(intent)
        return null
    }
}
```